# In a n-ary tree, find the number of greater children of each node in O(N)?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I am having an issue with my algorithm while trying to reduce its complexity. The specific problem has the following input:

- The first line is an integer N: the total number of nodes in an n-ary tree (1 <= N <= 10^5).
- The next N lines are the values of each node, called Vi, with 1 <= Vi <= 10^9.
- The following N-1 lines are the relationships between the child nodes and the parent node (from 2 to N), with the default first node being the root node.

**Result**:
Print N lines, each line containing the total number of child nodes (including lower-level child nodes) that have a value greater than their parent node.

**Example**:

```
Input
8
60
20
50
10
40
10
50
30
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
Output
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
```

This is my code, but in the worst case, it has to traverse everything, making its complexity O(N^2). I am hoping for a more optimal solution to reduce the complexity.

```
import sys
from collections import deque

def calculate(N, values, relations):
    tree = {i: [] for i in range(1, N + 1)}
    for i, parent in enumerate(relations, start=2):
        tree[parent].append(i)

    result = [0] * N

    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        stack = deque([(i, values[i - 1])]) 
        while stack:
            node, parent_value = stack.pop()
            for child in tree[node]:
                if values[child - 1] > parent_value:
                    result[i - 1] += 1
                stack.append((child, parent_value))

    return result

N = int(sys.stdin.readline())
values = [int(sys.stdin.readline()) for _ in range(N)]
relations = [int(sys.stdin.readline()) for _ in range(N - 1)]

for result in calculate(N, values, relations):
    print(result)
```

Comment: When you have processed a child node, you have no. of its children that satisfies that condition. When you go up, then for that parent, count is `(child node val > parent node val ? count[child node] + 1 : 0)`. Something like that..

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the nodes in reverse order to propagate results at the lower levels to their parents:

```
def calculate(N, values, relations):
    result = [0] * N
    for i in range(N - 1, 0, -1):
        result[parent := relations[i - 1] - 1] += result[i] + (values[parent] < values[i])
    return result
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZLNasMwDIBhRz2FYIfEWzKc_oxSlgfYJTvsGEIJrdMZUjs49mDPsksv20PtaSYnzrJLYbNByJI-S5b1_tm92RetzucPZ5t083V13Rh9QqlRnjptLD5bI9Xx8QngIBrc1-3etbUVcZHga9060SdoBFmkVj3bAtIyonetxRxLXuENFoOx0QYlSoWmVkfCMcUsQZ5gmgVsRsuuNkJZ3Obz3aX0RDWK23yKlHTAeKwkYBU-hNLIy0JF1hkVGAAreruTqnO-yOmBcRRFG7jnsOCw5pBxWA2S9CUpw17QXsIKKJR5MYb7DGuOA0HS60R4d0H3S2XjOeGdEfWhlUrEjMFYpW_U5aChcbtfjWMV_DTln6hvHuHg7eGTyPmnP-2MzzNCbJyVMDLT6HwD)

Note that the question requires the output for each node to include lower-level child nodes so the root node should have a total count of 2 instead of 0 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the nodes from the bottom of the tree first, so that you can "lift" these results into the rest of the tree. You have taken a breadth-first order approach, where you only know the result for the leaves of the tree when you have already processed the root (and upper part) of the tree, which means the results of the leaves are not accumulated into the results for the upper nodes.

A depth-first traversal, where you do the accumulation in post-order, will work better, and it doesn't even require that input lists the nodes in bread-first order. They may appear in any order (only the root should be the first):

```
def calculate(N, values, relations):
    tree = [[] for i in range(N)]  # I would use a list instead of dict
    for i, parent in enumerate(relations, start=1):
        tree[parent - 1].append(i)  # I would convert already here to 0-based
    
    result = [0] * N

    def dfs(node):
        for child in tree[node]:
            dfs(child)
            result[node] += result[child] + (values[child] > values[node])
        
    dfs(0)
    return result
```

The depth-first traversal becomes important when the input can have a child that has an identifier that is less than its parent.

For instance, the following tree defines the same tree as in your example, except that the node numbers are re-arranged (depicted before the colon):

```
                _____1:60__
               /      |    \
            6:20     7:50  8:10
           /   \      |     |
         2:40  3:10  4:50  5:30
```

Which means the input will be

```
8
60
40
10
50
30
20
50
10
6
6
7
8
1
1
1
```

...and stored like this:

```
N = 8
values =    [60,40,10,50,30,20,50,10]
relations =    [ 6, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1]
```

The above solution code will produce the following output for this altered input:

```
2
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
```